# Android check if using intent RECORD_SOUND_ACTION is available on device

Tags: android, android-intent, audio-recording

I use sound recording using Intents. On one my device RECORD_SOUND_ACTION is not accessible.
How can I check if RECORD_SOUND_ACTION is available on device ?

I use this part of code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Intent intent =
new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);  
if (isAvailable(getApplicationContext(), intent)) {  
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
} 

public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {  

   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();  

   List<ResolveInfo> list =  
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent,   
      PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);  

      return list.size() > 0;  

  }
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way it to check if the intent resolves before attempting to start it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

// Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
}
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ForceChooser